# my post request is not handled by playFramework routes however it is declared in route file

Tags: post, playframework-2.0, request

Hi everyone i am new play framework and my post is not working when i click a submit button the page renders back to the get request page.

let me describe the work flow : 
main page : code snippet

```
enter code here
<a href="@routes.Data.edit_frm()" ------->
```

when i click this hyperlink render a page which is  get request

controller : code snippet for the above page

```
public static Result edit_frm() {

    List<profile>temp_itr = null;


     if (check){
        System.out.println("connected to the database");
        temp_itr = DB_obj.get_allcollections();
        return ok(Edit.render(temp_itr));

    }

    return TODO;
```

}

the above controller fetchs to the get request and renders the page

template:snippet

```
enter code here

<div>
<form class="form-inline col-lg-8"  >
        <fieldset class="form-vertical">

          @helper.form(action=routes.Data.select_profile() ){
                 <input type="submit" value="submit">
                                        }
```

Routes :sniipet

```
enter code here

POST                   /edtfrm               controllers.Data.select_profile()
GET                    /edtfrm               controllers.Data.edit_frm()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `<form class="...">` and then using the `@helper.form` tag which will output another `<form>` HTML tag. Basically, you are embedding a `<form>` inside of another `<form>` and the inner one is probably getting ignored.

```
<div>
  @helper.form(routes.Data.select_profile(), 'class -> "form-inline col-lg-8"){
    <fieldset class="form-vertical">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">

      ...
  }
</div>
```